# Describe the image of following map $w= \frac{1}{z}$ with $|z-\frac {1}{2}| \leq \frac {1}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Describe the image of following map $w= \frac{1}{z}$ with $|z-\frac {1}{2}| \leq \frac {1}{2}$

I know that the inverse function map the inside of the circl to the outside of the circle and vice versa. Since $|z-\frac {1}{2}| \leq \frac {1}{2}$ I can tell that the domain is a disk with center is $1/2$ and radius also $1/2$. So if I let $w=u+iv$ then $ u \in [-\infty, 0] \cup [1,\infty]$

and $v\in [-\infty, -\frac {1}{2}]\cup [\frac {1}{2}, \infty]$.

I wonder if this is the correct answer, because the answer in the book is just $u \geq 1$

Comment: This is the domain $|w-2|\leqslant|w|$, that is, the points of affix $w$ that are at least as close to $2$ than to $0$. Geometrically, these are the points to the East of the [bisector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection#Line_segment_bisector) of $0$ and $2$, that is, to the right of the line $\Re=1$.

Comment: can you explain it a little bit further please? I really want to understand this stuff, otherwise, I can't move on to the following section

Comment: My comment fully explains a solution, it seems. Did you read it carefully? If you did and something is still unclear, can you explain further what exactly you want to see explained further?

Comment: yes, your comment explain the solution, but I really want to know how you get that solution? For the starter, please tell me, base on what you get $|w-2|\leq |w|$.

Comment: Based on $w= \frac{1}{z}$ and $|z-\frac {1}{2}| \leq \frac {1}{2}$, obviously. Hence $|\frac1w-\frac {1}{2}| \leq \frac {1}{2}$, hence...

Comment: I think I got it, thanks